# TestNG [6.9.12] fails to load in Eclipse Mars [4.5.2] -- org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException

Tags: eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

Expected behaviour

Should be possible to launch test via Run As -> TestNG ; also
should be able to add new Run configuration for TestNG

Actual behaviour

Plug-in org.testng.eclipse was unable to load class org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGTabGroup.
Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.testng.eclipse was unable to load class org.testng.eclipse.ui.TestNGQuickFixProcessor.
cannot be found by org.testng.eclipse_6.9.12.201607091356

Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.testng.eclipse was unable to load class org.testng.eclipse.ui.TestNGQuickFixProcessor.

Steps to reproduce

Install Eclipse Mars-2, 4.5.2
Install TestNG plugin from the Marketplace
Select an executable class
Attempt to "Run As TestNG"
Attempt to Run -> Run Configurations -> TestNG -> New
Running Configuration

Plugin Version: 6.9.12 [via eclipse marketplace]
(Optional) Operating System: Windows-10

Answer (score 1):

An issue already exists on the project: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/272